# SQL Inner join including NULL values

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm currently expanding a customer list query I wrote a few months ago to include more information about last periodic review. 
Work is running our data warehouse on Teradata SQL.
Here's a snippet of the code I'm working with, the actual query is about 200 lines.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
k.customerID
,k.name
,a.CountryCode
,CASE WHEN Account.actorID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS hasAccount
,id.ControlDate
,id.ControlBy
FROM customer k
LEFT JOIN agreement a ON k.actorID = a.actorID
LEFT JOIN identification id ON k.actorID = id.actorID
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT actorID, MAX(ControlDate) AS LastControl FROM identification GROUP BY actorID) id2 
   ON k.actorID = id2.actorID AND id.ControlDate = id2.LastControl
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT actorID FROM agreement a WHERE a.activeAgreement = 'Y' and a.Product IN ('6774', '6775') Account ON k.actorid = Account.actorID
WHERE
k.customerstatus = 'Active'
;
```

The trouble is with the `INNER JOIN` statement. 
When I run this, I get 1769 rows, but if I remove the `INNER JOIN` and the two `id`. phrases in `SELECT`, that sum pops up to 2117.
The difference is `NULL` values on `id.ControlDate`.

However, if I use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, I get approximately 6800 rows, since a lot of customers have been updated/performed control on multiple times. 
How can I fix this?

**Edit:** to clarify, I want one row per `actorID` where I either get the latest `controlDate` or `NULL` value

**Edit2:** as per request by @Thorsten Kettner, an explanation.
Both `ActorID` and `CustomerID` is unique per customer. However, this value is generated by the system, while `customerID` usually is a Social Security number, company registration number etc. We tend to use `CustomerID`  as a lookup value in our CRM system.
One customer (or actor) can have many agreements depending on their relationship with us, and many periodic reviews, as we are required by law to perform portfolio audits regularly.
And here are some sample data:

1) Without `INNER JOIN` statement:

> actorID   Customer_name   Country hasAccount  ControlDate ControlBy
>   278 228   BANK OF AMERICA NA TRADE OPERATION  US  0   ?   ?
>   275 330 Branch Banking And Trust Company    US  0   04.02.2016  AD09853
>   275 169   CITIZENS Bank NA    US  1   12.03.2018  AB96358
>   275 169   CITIZENS Bank
>   NA    US  1   16.11.2016  AB02890
>   275 169 CITIZENS Bank
>   NA    US  1   15.12.2015  AB62775
>   275 169 CITIZENS Bank
>   NA    US  1   11.10.2011  AB68786
>   264 072 Jp Morgan Chase Sec. Lending Asset
>   Management    US  0   11.10.2017  AB45546
>   264 061 International Development
>   Association   US  0   29.05.2018  AB45546
>   263 995 Zions Bancorporation
>   N.A   US  1   19.03.2015  AB43584
>   263 995 Zions Bancorporation
>   N.A   US  1   09.11.2016  AB02890
>   263 995 Zions Bancorporation
>   N.A   US  1   13.03.2018  AB45546
>   263 995 Zions Bancorporation
>   N.A   US  1   06.10.2011  AB68786
>   263 939 Citigroup Global Markets
>   Inc   US  1   22.12.2015  AB62775
>   263 939 Citigroup Global Markets
>   Inc   US  1   12.04.2012  AB68786
>   262 114 Prebon Financial Products
>   Inc   US  0   30.12.2015  AB24733
>   262 113 JP Morgan Securities
>   LLC   US  0   18.06.2018  AB45546
>   261 795 Federal Reserve
>   System    US  0   05.11.2015  AB62759
>    261 795    Federal Reserve
>   System    US  0   05.06.2014  AB31660

2) With `INNER JOIN` statement:

> actorID Customer_name Country hasAccount ControlDate ControlBy
>   275 330 Branch Banking And Trust Company US 0 04.02.2016 AD09853
>   275 169   CITIZENS Bank NA    US  1   12.03.2018  AB96358
>   264 072   Jp Morgan Chase Sec. Lending Asset Management   US  0   11.10.2017  AB45546
>   264 061   International Development Association   US  0   29.05.2018  AB45546
>   263 995   Zions Bancorporation N.A    US  1   13.03.2018  AB45546
>   263 939   Citigroup Global Markets Inc    US  1   22.12.2015  AB62775
>   262 114   Prebon Financial Products Inc   US  0   30.12.2015  AB24733
>   262 113   JP Morgan Securities LLC    US  0   18.06.2018  AB45546
>   261 795   Federal Reserve System  US  0   05.11.2015  AB62759

As you can see, `actorID 278 228` vanishes, which is not good...

Comment: You do not specify what you DO want, though. Maybe you want for each actorID one line, either with NULL if no ControlDate exists or with the most recent/oldest ControlDate?

Comment: That is exactly what I want, yes. Will update original post

Comment: On a sidenote: Whenever you are using `DISTINCT`, ask yourself why you need it. `DISTINCT` is something rarely needed. In your inner join subquery it is completely superfluous. And the left join subquery should be replaced with a mere condition in the where clause in my opinion: `and k.actorid in (select actorid from agreement where activeagreement = 'Y' and product in ('6774', '6775'))`.

Comment: On a sidenote again: According to your database design, one actor can be related to many customers and many agreements and many identifications. So for an actor ralated to 3 customers, 3 agreements, and 3 identifications, you'd produce 27 rows. But what else beside sharing the same actor has customer #2 to do with agreement #1 and identification #3? Are you sure your joins are correct?

Comment: If you show us some sample rows and the related expected result, we can probably help much better with your query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner original post is updated with more information and sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` on a `ROW_NUMBER` sort to get the records with the latest dates per customer only.

```
select 
  c.customerid,
  c.name,
  a.countrycode,
  case when c.actorid in 
    (select * from agreement where activeagreement = 'Y' and product in ('6774', '6775'))
   then 1 else 0 end as hasaccount,
  i.controldate,
  i.controlby
from customer c
left join agreement a on a.actorid = c.actorid
left join 
(
  select top 1 with ties *
  from identification
  order by row_number() over (partition by actorid order by controldate desc)
) i on i.actorid = c.actorid
where c.customerstatus = 'Active';
```

**UPDATE:** Above answer didn't work for the OP, so I offered the following two alternatives that did work:

```
left join
(
  select
    actorid, controlby, controldate,
    max(controlby) over (partition by actorid) as max_controldate
  from identification
) i on i.actorid = c.actorid and i.controldate = i.max_controldate.
```

and

```
left join
(
  select *
  from identification
  qualify row_number() over (partition by actorid order by controldate desc) = 1)
) i on i.actorid = c.actorid. – Thorsten
```

The last option with `QUALIFY` is the teradata way to do this. `QUALIFY` is a teradata extension to the SQL standard. The other two approaches are standard SQL.

Comment: From what I can gather, this seems like a pretty elegant solution. However, Teradata is throwing me a `SELECT failed. 6916: TOP N Syntax Error`
Any ideas as to why, or a workaround?

Comment: I don't know, why it doesn't work. One alternative is `left join (select actorid, controlby, controldate, max(controlby) over (partition by actorid) as max_controldate from identification) i on i.actorid = c.actorid and i.controldate = i.max_controldate`.

Comment: I just read that in Teradata you can also use `QUALIFY`: `left join (select * from identification qualify row_number() over (partition by actorid order by controldate desc) = 1)) i on i.actorid = c.actorid`.

Comment: Both the above solutions work beautifully :) Update the answer with the two additional solutions and I will mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably the quickest solution would be to use ISNULL.
Where you write `MAX(ControlDate)` extend it with `MAX(ISNULL(ControlDate,'1970-01-01'))` (or any default date that you have)

That would replace the NULLs and make your query work.

I hope it helps.
Peter

Comment: ISNULL produces the following: 
SELECT Failed. 3706:  Syntax error: Data Type "ControlDate" does not match a Defined Type name.

Comment: I am not sure what is your database's regional setting is. Probably it cannot convert the text to date. You could try '01/01/1970' for example.

Comment: Outside of syntax issues, semantically you would have to pair this with a change to the inner join ON condition

Comment: Based on your output above you could also try 


`MAX(ISNULL(ControlDate,'01.01.1980'))` , if the syntax is still an issue.

And Andrew is right, you would need to do the same at the ON condition. (And in the output if you want to show the default date)